# Definition of $p$-torsion free

Tags: commutative-algebra, definition

I know that torsion free means that there is no torsion element (elements s.t. $ann(x)=0$) except for $0$. But I don't know what $p$-torsion free exactly means. Such definition doesn't appear in my several commutative algebra books.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In my experience, $p$-torsion free has meant that the only solution of $px=0$ is $x=0$. (Here $p$ is a prime natural number and $x$ refers to elements of an abelian group. So $px$ means $x+\cdots+x$ with $p$ summands. The meaning of $p$-torsion free might be different in other contexts, but I'd expect  the general idea to  be the same.)

Comment: Thank you very much!